# Data not Loading into GridView (Ch 31 Introducing ASP.NET WEB FORMS)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to implement the Single-File Web Forms Web App in Ch 31 of c# 6.0 and the .NET 4.6 Framework of A. Troelsen / P. Japiske. But I fail in getting the data of AutoLot displayed in the browser.

As suggested by the authors I coded default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="MySinglePageModel.Default" %>
```

and

```
<script runat="server">
    public IEnumerable<Inventory> GetData()
    {
        return new InventoryRepo().GetAll();
    }
</script>
```

and

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="carsGridView" runat="server"
            ItemType="AutoLotDAL.Models.Inventory"
            SelectMethod="GetData">

        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</form>
```

and tried connection strings in the web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="AutoLotConnection"
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AutoLot;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFrameWork"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

or

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="AutoLotConnection"
     connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=AutoLot;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFrameWork"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

The SelectMethod apparently is not properly executed and the data are not loaded into GridView.
Can anybody give a hint what I am missing?

Here is the default.aspx file complete:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="MySinglePageModel.Default" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="AutoLotDAL.Models" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="AutoLotDAL.Repos" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />

   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
   <title>MySinglePageModel</title>
   </head>
       <script runat="server">
       public IEnumerable<Inventory> GetData()
       {
        return new InventoryRepo().GetAll();    
       }      
    </script>
 <body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <div>
           <asp:GridView ID="carsGridView" runat="server"
             ItemType="AutoLotDAL.Models.Inventory"
             SelectMethod="GetData"> 
           </asp:GridView>
         </div>
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DataBind()` method to bind data from a data source to the GridView control like this:

```
    <script runat="server">
    public IEnumerable<Inventory> GetData()
    {
        return new InventoryRepo().GetAll();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)            
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            carsGridView.DataSource = GetData();
            carsGridView.DataBind();
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: First, many thanks for your comments, but I get the following error: $exception {"DataSource oder DataSourceID kann nicht für \"carsGridView\" definiert werden, wenn Modellbindung verwendet wird."}
System.InvalidOperationException
i.e.
{DataSource or DataSourceID can not be defined for \"carsGridView\" if modelbinding is applied. Sorry that I am not yet familiar with asp.net, I am working on that, kind regards Haraqld

Comment: I have reedited my question and entered the complete default.aspx file as it is in my program. I have also loaded the program of the authors of the book on to google drive which can be found under https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I2d9x9KIu1hJe6EiEbHI_i6aL7x4JdbO. I also have placed this question at the respective site of apress, thanks for your interest, perhaps it works some day....

Comment: Did you restore the AutoLot database? Also, what was the first error you see?

Comment: There are apparently no programming errors. My problem is that my default.aspx produces an empty web page and no listing of AutoLot data, while there is file  C:\Users\myName\AutoLot.mdf. Testing the connection in server explorer with datasource = Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient),  servername = (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB, authentication = Windows-Authentifizierung and name of database=AutoLot is positive. Where are the data?

Comment: Mostly you database in empty try to select data from Inventory table and post the result